# Attach file stored in ContentVersion object to ServiceNow Incident

Tags: rest-api, fileupload, servicenow

I'm writing an integration in Salesforce where users can create an Incident in ServiceNow from within Salesforce. I'm able to create the Incident fine from Salesforce. I need to be able to attach a file which is stored in our ContentVersion object to the newly created Incident in ServiceNow using REST API.  I wrote an apex class but keep getting a 400 error response.  Here is my existing apex code. I've hardcoded references for the sake of debugging.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class UploadFileToServiceNowIncident  {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Upload File to Incident' description='Attach a file to an Incident')
    public static List<Output> OutputResult(List<Request> InputPrm){
        String bodyBase64;
        String boundary = '__boundary__xxx';
        String footer = '\n--'+boundary+'--';

        ContentVersion file = [SELECT Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE IsLatest = TRUE and ContentDocumentId='0697j000002A2ziAAC'];
        bodyBase64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file.VersionData);
        //String header = '--'+boundary+'\n'
             //+ 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="'+file.Title
             //+'"\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\n\n';
 
        
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String username = 'username';
        String password = 'password';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    //  request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','text/txt');
        request.setHeader('Accept','application/json,text/plain,*/*');      
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint('https://sertasimmonssandbox.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=incident&table_sys_id=b5f33dfcdb8d7910e96a4c9d13961986&file_name=call batchable class.txt');   
        request.setBody(bodyBase64);
    //  request.setTimeout(60000);
        
    
        Http http = new Http();
        System.HttpResponse resp = http.send(request);
        System.debug('value of request '+ request);
        System.debug('value of resp ' + resp);
        List<Output> Result = new List<Output>();
        string out =  resp.getBody();
        System.debug('value of out ' + out);
        Output op = new Output();
        op.ResponseCode = resp.toString();
        Result.add(op);
        return Result;

    }
```

Comment: Error 400 means bad request typically something incorrect in the HTTP header or body. Did you test this request in a third-party tool first like Postman to confirm your HTTP headers and body are constructed correctly and there is no problem at the server itself before trying to debug the problem in Apex?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working apex class that will upload a file from Salesforce Files (`ContentVersion` object) to a ServiceNow Incident.  This class is being called from a Salesforce flow.  The flow creates the Incident and then I created an apex callout action to add the attachment to the newly created Incident.

```
public class UploadFileToServiceNowIncident  {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Upload File to Incident' description='Attach a file to an Incident')
    public static List<Output> OutputResult(List<Request> InputPrm){
        
        ContentVersion fileBody = [SELECT Title, FileExtension, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE IsLatest = TRUE and ContentDocumentId =: InputPrm[0].ContentDocId];

        String fileName = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(fileBody.Title, 'UTF-8') + '.' + fileBody.FileExtension; 
               
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String username = 'username';
        String password = 'password';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');     
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint('https://myservicenoworg.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=incident&table_sys_id=' + InputPrm[0].SysId + '&file_name=' + fileName); 
        System.debug('value of endPoint ' + request.getEndpoint());

        request.setBodyAsBlob(fileBody.VersionData);
        
    
        Http http = new Http();
        System.HttpResponse resp = http.send(request);
        System.debug('value of request '+ request);
        System.debug('value of resp ' + resp);
        List<Output> Result = new List<Output>();
        string out =  resp.getBody();
        System.debug('value of out ' + out);
        Output op = new Output();
        op.ResponseCode = resp.toString();
        Result.add(op);
        return Result;

    }

     //Input from flow
    public class Request{
    
        @InvocableVariable(label='Sys_Id' required = true)
        public String SysId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='ContentDocument Id' required = true)
        public String ContentDocId;
    }
    
    //Output to flow
    public class Output{
    
        @InvocableVariable (label='Response Code')
        public String ResponseCode;
    }
}
```